# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm getting the above error when creating a new record.  I don't want to insert the identity -- the database has it auto generated and that is great.

Here is the exact exception:

```
[System.Data.UpdateException]
{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PartRevisions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}
```

Here are the mappings:

```
Public Class PartContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Parts As DbSet(Of Part)
    Public Property PartRevisions As DbSet(Of PartRevision)


    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of PartRevision)().HasKey(Function(r) r.Id).Property(Function(r) r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    End Sub

End Class

<Table("Parts")>
Public Class Part
    <Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    Public Property Id As Integer

    Public Property PartNumber As String
    Public Property Owner As String
End Class

<Table("PartRevisions")>
Public Class PartRevision
    Inherits Part

    Public Property OriginalId As Integer
    Public Property RevisionDate As DateTime
    Public Property RevisionNumber As Integer
    Public Property RevisionBy As String

End Class
```

If I don't use inheritance it works fine.  If I make Id overridable and also specify the attributes on the sub class it still doesn't work.

I'm doing the `OnModelCreating` stuff just because I'm trying to get it to work.  I feel like it should work without this.  Of course it doesn't even work with this...

The following query works fine when I execute it in SQL Management Studio:

```
insert into PartRevisions (originalid, revisiondate, revisionnumber, revisionby, partnumber, owner)
values (1, '1/1/2013', 1, 'eep', '123', 'ME')
```

Here is a gist with the full program.  I was trying this out in a test project because I assumed I'd run into some issues doing inheritance in EF (never done yet).

https://gist.github.com/eyston/4956444

Thanks!

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: added exception to body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PartRevisions` table must not have the `Id` column set as an autogenerated identity, only the table `Parts` for the base type. The two tables have shared primary keys. EF joins the two tables when it queries a `PartRevision` and it inserts rows into both tables if a `PartRevision` entity is inserted. Because both rows must have the same `Id` only one can be an identity.

Comment: Thanks.  I just removed Parts from the Context and it works great.  Is there a way to configure EF that PartRevisions should share nothing with Parts in terms of tables?

Comment: @eyston: No, it's the way how inheritance in your model is mapped to the database schema, basically: Derived class => Shared primary key between the tables. At least this is the case for Table-Per-Type inheritance (TPT) which you have configured by applying the `<Table("PartRevisions")>` attribute. You could also use Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) (by removing that attribute). EF would then expect all columns for base and derived types in a single table (`Parts`) = No joins between tables.

Comment: I just made a 'BasePart' that both inherit from and it works.  I didn't realize this would be treated differently than what I was doing already.  I'm not sure if this is what I want to do, I just wanted to try this out and get an idea of different ways of handling.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the auto identity property from the "Id" column. Or alternatively you can use in your Query/Stored procedure. This will enable to to enter explicit Id values into your table even if auto identity on column is set. (Though not a good idea to use always but its good for fixes)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.YourTableName ON;
GO
```

Then after each table's inserts:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.YourTableName OFF;
GO
```